# Circular Motion and Conservation of Energy Question

Tags: classical-mechanics

[image]
A particle $P$ of mass m is connected to a fixed point $O$ by a light inextensible string $OP$ of length $r$ and is moving in a vertical circle, centre $O$. At its lowest point, $P$ has speed $U$. When the string makes an angle of $\alpha$ with the downward vertical it encounters a small fixed peg $Q$ where $OQ = \frac{r}{2}$. The string proceeds to wrap itself around the peg, so that $P$ begins to move in a vertical circle with center $Q$ (see diagram). Given that the particle describes a complete circle about $Q$, show that $U^2 \ge gr(\frac{7}{2}-cos\alpha)$

$Note$: The line $OQ$ is solid from $O$ to $Q$ and dotted from $Q$ onward.

Here is what I did:- First I found the difference in height between the lowest point and the highest point as $h=\frac{3r}{2} - \frac{r}{2}cos\alpha$.
Then using conservation of energy I said $\frac{1}{2}mU^2= \frac{1}{2}mV^2 +mgh$
Then for the particle at the highest point I used $mg +T = \frac{mv^2}{r}$, made $T$ the subject, made a substitution for $V^2$ using the previous expression and finally set $T\ge0$. I have redone my working a couple of times but was unable to arrive at the given result. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Where did you find this problem ?

Comment: It is from one of the past examination papers of the subject Further Mathematics offered by Cambridge at A level. Why?

Comment: If the problem belongs to a textbook, it can be useful to read the context. No other reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $P$ is at its highest point above Q, it has a speed enough to make a loop. String tension is at least $0$.

$$mg + T = \frac {mV^2}{r/2} \implies V \ge \sqrt {\frac{gr}2}$$

By conservation of energy, at the lowest point which is $h = \frac32r-\frac12r\cos\alpha$ units lower,

$$\begin{align*}
\frac12mU^2 &= \frac12mV^2 + mgh\\
U^2 &\ge \frac{gr}2 +g(3r-r\cos\alpha) \\
&= gr\left(\frac72-\cos\alpha\right)
\end{align*}$$